# Is previous pointer destroyed when using = operator in std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Does the previous pointer automatically get destroyed (or dereferenced) in an std::shared_ptr if I assign a new one to it with the = operator?

For example:

```
std::shared_ptr< Type > sp1 (ptr1, std::ptr_fun(destroy));
std::shared_ptr< Type > sp2 (ptr2);

sp1 = sp2; // now, will ptr1 be dereferenced and / or destroyed?
// and will the destroy() function get called?
```

Comment: Of course, otherwise it would leak.

Comment: why you dont try it yourself ?

Comment: Imo, if a smart pointer implementation didn't properly handle simple assignment... it's not a very smart pointer.

Comment: AFAICT it's even supposed to handle `sp1 = sp1` ie self-assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, or else you would have a leak and it would defeat the purpose of having a smart ptr.

Just made a quick test and I didn't get any leaks

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE leakTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( Leak_Test )
{
    std::shared_ptr< int > sp1 (new int(3));
    std::shared_ptr< int > sp2 (new int(4));

    sp1 = sp2;
}
```

Results:

> Running 1 test case...
>
> *** No errors detected Press any key to continue .

. .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. shared_ptr is a data structure which has an internal object which actually keeps original pointer. This internal object has an counter that is incremented every time we copy shared_ptr and is decremented when shared_ptr is being destroyed or being assigned another shared_ptr. As soon as the counted goes down to zero the internal object is destroyed together with the original pointer.

In you case:

```
std::shared_ptr< Type > sp1 (ptr1, std::ptr_fun(destroy)); //the counter of sp1 is 1
std::shared_ptr< Type > sp2 (ptr2); //the counter of sp2 is 1
sp1 = sp2; //the counter of sp1 is 0, the counter of sp2 is 2
```

so, ptr1 will be destroyed and sp1 and sp2 will share the same pointer ptr2